# Weighted Decision Trees using Entropy

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, decision-tree

I'm building a binary classification tree using [mutual information gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) as the splitting function. But since the training data is skewed toward a few classes, it is advisable to weight each training example by the inverse class frequency.

How do I weight the training data? When calculating the probabilities to estimate the entropy, do I take weighted averages?

EDIT: I'd like an expression for entropy with the weights.

Comment: Isn't the inverse class frequency your weighting factor?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question, "it is advisable to weight each training example by the inverse class frequency."

Comment: I assume you already knew about the Wiki info.  So what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question and commented the answer to reflect the new changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**State-value weighted entropy as a measure of investment risk.**
http://www56.homepage.villanova.edu/david.nawrocki/State%20Weighted%20Entropy%20Nawrocki%20Harding.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article you cited goes into weighting.  It says:

**Weighted variants**
In the traditional formulation of the mutual information,

[image]

each event or object specified by (x,y) is weighted by the corresponding probability p(x,y). This assumes that all objects or events are equivalent apart from their probability of occurrence. However, in some applications it may be the case that certain objects or events are more significant than others, or that certain patterns of association are more semantically important than others.

For example, the deterministic mapping {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)} may be viewed as stronger (by some standard) than the deterministic mapping {(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)}, although these relationships would yield the same mutual information. This is because the mutual information is not sensitive at all to any inherent ordering in the variable values (Cronbach 1954, Coombs & Dawes 1970, Lockhead 1970), and is therefore not sensitive at all to the form of the relational mapping between the associated variables. If it is desired that the former relation — showing agreement on all variable values — be judged stronger than the later relation, then it is possible to use the following weighted mutual information (Guiasu 1977)

[image]

which places a weight w(x,y) on the probability of each variable value co-occurrence, p(x,y). This allows that certain probabilities may carry more or less significance than others, thereby allowing the quantification of relevant holistic or prägnanz factors. In the above example, using larger relative weights for w(1,1), w(2,2), and w(3,3) would have the effect of assessing greater informativeness for the relation {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)} than for the relation {(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)}, which may be desirable in some cases of pattern recognition, and the like.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Weighted_variants

Comment: Yes, I realized this. I was hoping for a weighted version of entropy. I use various entropy estimates to calculate a scores similar to mutual information.