# MATLAB indexing question

Tags: matlab, indexing, matrix

I have a matrix, for example

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] ;
```

and a vector of size 1x3 which specifies which element in each row is the one I'm looking for - i.e. If

```
vector = [ 1 2 1 ]
```

then the desired output is

```
[ 1 5 7 ]
```

since `1` is the 1'st element in the 1'st row, `5` is the 2'nd in the 2'nd row, and `7` is the 1'st element in the 3'rd row.

How do I achieve this? Couldn't find a built in function to do this, which surprised me.

Comment: Related: [Accessing values using subscripts without using sub2ind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146719/accessing-values-using-subscripts-without-using-sub2ind)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the indexes in Matlab go from top to bottom.
So in your case **A[1] = 1 , A[2] = 4 , A[3] = 7**

That said, it would be easier to work on A' , because its a bit more trivial.

```
B = A';

B((vector + [0:2].* 3))
```

Comment: From the documentation: *"A(:) is all the elements of A, regarded as a single column."*. As a side note in order to understand the indexing.

Answer (score 8):

MATLAB provides the [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html) function to convert rows/columns subscripts to linear indices:

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> idx = sub2ind(size(A),1:3,[1 2 1]);  %# rows: [1 2 3], cols: [1 2 1]
>> A(idx)
     1     5     7
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit ugly, but `diag(A(1:3,[1 2 1]))` will do the trick.

Comment: I did the same thing: diag(A(:,vector))'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of [Yochai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842512/matlab-indexing-question/4842559#4842559) but without the transpose (this is also basically what [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html) does in [Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842512/matlab-indexing-question/4843227#4843227)):

```
 output = A((1:3)+3.*(vector-1));
```

Or for an array `A` of an arbitrary size:

```
 nRows = size(A,1);
 output = A((1:nRows)+nRows.*(vector-1));
```