# How to extract non-vertical column from matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

I have matrix A and a vector b, which specifies column index of the element to be extracted for each corresponding row of the matrix.

For example,

```
A = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9]

b = [1 3 2]'
```

I'd like to have `c = [1 6 8]'` on output. How to achieve this?

I tried `A(:, b)`, but it doesn't work as I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB indexing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842512/matlab-indexing-question)

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
b = [1 3 2]';
[rows, cols] = size(A);
A(sub2ind([rows cols], [1 : rows]', b))
```

Comment: Avoid using `[]` when you mean `()` because it'll cause unnecessary calls to `horzcat` and `vertcat` (I expect).

Comment: Interesting.  I always think of `[]` as "whatever's in here is an array".  I know that's not the technical truth, but it's what I think when I'm reading/writing code.  I assume that you mean that `[1 : rows]'` could be `(1 : rows)'`.  In my (admittedly flawed) mental model of what's going on, I'm saying "I want a column vector from 1 to rows."  Seems like the order of operations would be such that there would be no calls to horzcat there?  I.e., we get something like `temp1 = 1 : rows`, `temp2 = [temp1]` (no horzcat b/c there's only one object), `temp3 = temp2'`.

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure how clever the MATLAB parser is in this case. Certainly if you have an object, `o`, and you write `[o]`, then it will call the `horzcat` and `vertcat` methods. Also, it's generally worth following the M-Lint advice regardless.

Comment: Old habits die hard :)

I was really curious about this, so I did a little profiling.  I wrote three functions calculating: `[1 : 10].'`,  `(1 : 10).'`, and `[(1 : 10).']`.  I ran the profiler on a script that called each function 100,000 times.  `[(1 : 10).']` was actually consistently the fastest by about 0.1 sec.(?!)

Obviously this is not at all rigorous, but *for me* the moral of the story is that the readability of `[1 : N]` is worth the tiny performance hit (at least for N reasonably small).  Speaking only on behalf of myself, of course.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @dantswain's solution, you can go to the linear indices directly, assuming you're always selecting from the columns:

```
r = size(A,1);
A( (1:r).' + (b-1) * r)
```

This will be faster, but not necessarily clearer.

Unfortunately, there isn't an elegant solution.