# Pick out entries of a matrix given specified columns in Matlab without a for loop

Tags: matlab, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB indexing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842512/matlab-indexing-question)
>   [How to extract non-vertical column from matrix in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721240/how-to-extract-non-vertical-column-from-matrix-in-matlab)

I feel like there should be a simple way to do what I want, but I cannot figure this out.

**INPUT**: an `n x t` matrix `M` of reals and an `n x 1` vector `I` of indices

**OUTPUT**: an `n x 1` vector `P` such that `P(i) = M( i, I(i) )`

It's obvious how to do this with a `for` loop, but this is Matlab and `n` is large. Is there a way to vectorize this problem and avoid the `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple, fast, vectorized solution using linear indexing.

```
indx = (1:n)' + (I-1)*n; %'
P=M(indx);
```

---

#### Example:

```
M = randi(10,[3,4]);     %# test matrix

M =

     9    10     3    10
    10     7     6     2
     2     1    10    10

n = size(M,1);
I = [3,1,4]';            %'# index vector
indx = (1:n)' + (I-1)*n; %'
P = M(indx)

P =

 3
10
10
```

Comment: Perfect. I didn't think about flattening the matrix.