# Select separate rows per column

Tags: matlab, octave

Say

```
X = [1 2;
     3 4];
c = [1 2]';
```

I would like to find some way of doing what it seems to me like `X(:,c)` should do. To write it as a for loop:

```
for i=1:n
   res(i) = X(i, c(i));
end
% res = [1 4]
```

is there a single statement / vectorized way of doing this?

Comment: similar question: [MATLAB indexing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4842512/97160)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`diag(X(:,c))` should do the trick

Explanation:
A (slightly more complicated) example will help understand.

```
>>X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]

X =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8

>> c = [1 1 2 1];
>> R = X(:,c)

R =

     1     1     2     1
     3     3     4     3
     5     5     6     5
     7     7     8     7
```

So what's going on here?  For each element in vector `c`, you're picking one of the columns from the original matrix `X`: For the first column of `R`, use the first column of `X`.  For the second column of `R`, use the first column of `X` (again).  For the third column of `R`, use the second column of `X`... and so on.

The effect of this is that the element you're interested in (defined in `c`) is located along the diagonal of the matrix `R`.  Get just the diagonal using `diag`:

```
>>diag(R)

ans =

1
3
6
7
```

Comment: This only works for the example Xodarap provided, if `c` isn't coincidentally equal to `1:length(X)`, this will not do what he requested, ie retrieve `X(i, c(i))`

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Sure it will: `X=[1 2 3;4 5 6]; c=[3 1]; diag(X(:,c)) -> [6 1]`.  Note that I didn't do `diag(X)` but rather `diag` on a matrix formed from the columns of `X` specified in `c`

Comment: You're right that this works, but could you explain why? I don't really understand what `X(:,c)` is returning me.

Comment: @Xodarap Explanation added... let me know if you need more, or if that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Use [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert to [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)

```
X = [1 2;
     3 4];
c = [1 2]';

idx = sub2ind(size(X),1:numel(c),c(:)');
res = X(idx);
```

(I used `c(:)'` to get `c` in the correct size.)

Result:

```
res =

 1     4
```