# How can I resolve out of memory error in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate 2 covariance matrices with size (10304,1034) and matlab creates the first one but when it runs the second command, this error occurs:

```
>> j=ones(10000,10000);
>> jj=ones(10000,10000);
??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

My laptop's RAM is 2GB, but it still has 1 GB free. I am using Windows 7 and 32-bit MATLAB 2009b.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you try matlab's support? Not sure whether this is programming related.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html

Comment: Perhaps you can just calculate one, `save` the result, `clear` the workspace, and calculate the second one? Also a different datatype might do the trick/

Comment: The problem is fixed in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277298/matlab-out-of-memory-error

Answer (score 7):

A 10k-by-10k array of doubles uses 1e8*8 bytes, which corresponds to 800MB. MATLAB needs these 800MB to be contiguous. Most likely, your 1GB free memory is a little fragmented, so MATLAB cannot fit the new array into RAM.

Use the command [MEMORY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/memory.html) to find out the maximum variable size that MATLAB can handle at a given moment.

Comment: By the way, the memory is not available as a call on all platforms. I think it is only found on PC installations.

Comment: Indeed. But the OP is running Windows 7, so for them it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use sparse matrices, in that case MATLAB doesn't allocate the entire space.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these two options little bit increase in memory allocated for matlab.exe processing.

1- Give higher priority to Matlab.exe task. You can do that by going to task manager, Processes tab, right click the Matlab.exe Task, select priority and set it to higher priority (say real time), this tells Windows to allocate more resources to this process.

2- Increase the page file size of your applications in general. You can do this by right clicking MyComputer ->properties->Advanced System Settings ->Advanced-> Performance->Virtual Memory (change..). Then the tick from the Automatic .... and set the initial and maximum page size to say 10000 MB.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Matlab-->file-->Preferences-->general-->Java heap memory--> and increase the level.. This solved my problem