# Is there a way in which I can increase the memory available to matlab?

Tags: matlab, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [matlab error “Out of memory”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422502/matlab-error-out-of-memory)

I am trying to run a tensor decomposition for a huge tensor of dimensions close to 10000 * 300 * 100 in matlab. But I am running out of memory for storing the tensor let alone compute the decomposition. Is there a way that I can instruct matlab to give me more memory when I run out of memory?

I have 4 GB of RAM. So it should in principle be possible to get 2.4 GB for the tensor (assuming that each element of the tensor is taking 8 bytes). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you running a 64bit version?

Comment: Also memory fragments and you need 2.4GB of *contiguous* memory. You may not have that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422502/matlab-error-out-of-memory?rq=1

Comment: Its 32 bit Windows. In case of fragmentation, I am supposing that matlab won't be able to do anything?

Comment: Correct, If you go to the link in my third comment and use the command in the accepted answer, it will tell you the maximum amount of memory MATLAB is able to provide at the time. If your requested allocation is under *that* number, then come back to SO

Comment: You can try the `/3GB` switch in boot.ini.  But most likely you need to break your problem into smaller chucks that each fit in memory.

Comment: If you want non-contiguous memory, consider using cell array.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you really need a dense array of that size...) One approach might be to use [distributed arrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/parallel/distarrays.html) from the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/index.html) (PCT). This lets you spread a single array across the RAM of multiple machines. You'd also need as many [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/distriben/) licences as workers you need.

Not all functions are available for distributed arrays, but a good number of core arithmetic and linear algebra functions are implemented - list [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/using-matlab-functions-on-codistributed-arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have enough RAM, you could do some computations 'out-of-core', allocating the data on the disk. Have a look at the [VVAR fileexchange project](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34276-vvar-class-a-fast-virtual-variable-class-for-matlab). I did not use it, but the description might fit what you need. The created arrays can be used in normal matlab fashion, and they are seamlessly saved to HDD when needed.