# MATLAB Error:Out of Memory

Tags: matlab

So I'm trying to perform STFT on a piano recording using matlab, but I get the following error.
Warning: Input arguments must be scalar.

```
In test3 at 35
??? Error using ==> zeros
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> test3 at 35
song = cat(1,song,zeros(n_of_padding,1));
```

The coding I've used is taken from a sample code found on the net.

```
clc;
clear all;

[song,FS] = wavread('c scale fast.wav');
song = sum(song,2);
song = song/max(abs(song));

wTime = 0.05;
ZP_exp = 1;
P_OL = 50;

% Number of STFT samples per STFT slice
N_window = floor(wTime*FS);

% Number of overlapping points
window_overlap = floor(N_window*(P_OL/100));

wTime = N_window/FS;

%size checking
%make sure there are integer number of windows if not zero pad until they are
L = size(song);

%determine the number of times-1 the overlapping window will fit the song length
N_of_windows = floor(L - N_window/(N_window - window_overlap));

%determine the remainder
N_of_points_left = L - (N_window + N_of_windows*(N_window - window_overlap));

%Calculate the number of points to zero pad
n_of_padding = (N_window - window_overlap) - N_of_points_left;

%append the zeros to the end of the song
song = cat(1,song,zeros(n_of_padding,1));

clear n_of_windows n_of_points_left n_of_padding
n_of_windows = floor((L - N_window)/(N_window - window_overlap))+1;
windowing = hamming(N_window);
N_padding = 2^(nextpow2(N_window)+ZP_exp);

parfor k = 1:N_of_windows
    starting = (k-1)*(N_window -window_overlap) +1;
    ending = starting+N_window-1;

    %Define the Time of the window, i.e., the center of window
    times(k) = (starting + ceil(N_window/2))/Fs;

    %apply windowing function
    frame_sample = music(starting:ending).*windowing;

    %take FFT of sample and apply zero padding
    F_trans = fft(frame_sample,N_padding);

    %store FFT data for later
    STFT_out(:,k) = F_trans;
end
```

Comment: Did you try what the error recommends? Please provide the output from `help memory` for your 32 or 64 bit version (whichever you are using) and provide the size of `n_of_padding`.

Comment: -1 for not posting the information you got when you did what Matlab told you to do and executed `help memory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 35 you are trying to make an array that exceeds your available memory. Note that a 1 by n array of zeros alone, is `n*8` bytes in size. This means if you make such an array, call it `x`, and check it with `whos('x')`, like:

```
x = zeros(10000,1);
whos('x');
```

You will likely find that `x` is 80000 bytes. Maybe by adding such an array to your `song` variable is adding the last bytes that breaks the memory-camel's back. Using and `whos('variableName')` take whatever the size of `song` is before line 35, separately add the size of `zeros(n_of_padding,1)`, convert that to MB, and see if it exceeds your maximum possible memory given by `help memory`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some assumptions I would reason that:
- n_of_padding should be smaller than N_window 
- N_window is much smaller FS
- Fs is not too high (frequency of your sound, so should not exceed a few thousand?!)
- Your zeros matrix will not be huge

This should mean that the problem is not that you are creating a too large matrix, but that you already filled up the memory before this call.

---

How to deal with this?

- First type `dbstop if error`
- Run your code
- When it stops check all variable sizes to see where the space has gone.

If you don't see anything strange (and the big storage is really needed) then you may be able to process your song in parts.

Answer (score 0):

The most common implication of `Out of memory` errors on Matlab is that it is unable to allocate memory due to the lack of a contiguous block. This **[article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html)** explains the various reasons that can cause an `Out of memory` error on MATLAB.

The `Out of memory` error often points to a faulty implementation of code that expands matrices on the fly (concatenating, out-of-range indexing). In such scenarios, MATLAB creates a copy in memory i.e memory twice the size of the matrix is consumed with each such occurrence.

On Windows this problem can be alleviated to some extent by passing the `/3GB /USERVA=3030` switch during boot as explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287367/319204). This enables additional virtual memory to be addressed by the application(MATLAB in this case).